# Decrease distance from slider item to navigation bar

Tags: css

I will like to make my slider item closer to the navigation bar (black horizontal line) as shown on www.dailycrazydeals.com.

Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/LdCnK/4/embedded/result/

And the css is:

```
 .mi-slider {
position: relative;
margin-top: 30px;
height: 490px;
 }

 .mi-slider ul {
list-style-type: none;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
bottom: 140px;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
pointer-events: none;
}

.no-js .mi-slider ul {
position: relative;
left: auto;
bottom: auto;
margin: 0;
overflow: visible;
}

.mi-slider ul.mi-current {
pointer-events: auto;
}

.mi-slider ul li {
display: inline-block;
padding: 20px;
width: 20%;
max-width: 300px;
-webkit-transform: translateX(600%);
transform: translateX(600%);
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
}

.no-js .mi-slider ul li {
-webkit-transform: translateX(0);
transform: translateX(0);
}

.mi-slider ul li a,
.mi-slider ul li img {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.mi-slider ul li a {
outline: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.mi-slider ul li img {
max-width: 100%;
border: none;
}

.mi-slider ul li h4 {
display: inline-block;
font-family: Baskerville, "Baskerville Old Face", "Hoefler Text", Garamond, "Times New Roman", serif;
font-style: italic;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 18px;
padding: 20px 10px 0;
}

.mi-slider ul li:hover {
opacity: 0.7;
} 

.mi-slider nav {
position: relative;
top: 400px;
text-align: center;
max-width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
border-top: 5px solid #333;
}

.no-js nav {
display: none;
}

.mi-slider nav a {
display: inline-block;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 5px;
padding: 40px 30px 30px 34px;
position: relative;
color: #888;
outline: none;
-webkit-transition: color 0.2s linear;
transition: color 0.2s linear;
}

.mi-slider nav a:hover,
.mi-slider nav a.mi-selected {
color: #000;
 }

.mi-slider nav a.mi-selected:after,
.mi-slider nav a.mi-selected:before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: -5px;
border: solid transparent;
height: 0;
width: 0;
position: absolute;
pointer-events: none;
}

.mi-slider nav a.mi-selected:after {
border-color: transparent;
border-top-color: #fff;
border-width: 20px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -20px;
}

.mi-slider nav a.mi-selected:before {
border-color: transparent;
border-top-color: #333;
border-width: 27px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -27px;
}

/* Move classes and animations */

.mi-slider ul:first-child li,
.no-js .mi-slider ul li {
-webkit-animation: scaleUp 350ms ease-in-out both;
animation: scaleUp 350ms ease-in-out both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scaleUp {
0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0) scale(0); }
100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0) scale(1); }
}

@keyframes scaleUp {
0% { transform: translateX(0) scale(0); }
100% { transform: translateX(0) scale(1); }
}

.mi-slider ul:first-child li:first-child {
-webkit-animation-delay: 90ms;
animation-delay: 90ms;
}

.mi-slider ul:first-child li:nth-child(2) {
-webkit-animation-delay: 180ms;
animation-delay: 180ms;
}

.mi-slider ul:first-child li:nth-child(3) {
-webkit-animation-delay: 270ms;
animation-delay: 270ms;
}

.mi-slider ul:first-child li:nth-child(4) {
-webkit-animation-delay: 360ms;
animation-delay: 360ms;
}

/* moveFromRight */

.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromRight li {
-webkit-animation: moveFromRight 350ms ease-in-out both;
animation: moveFromRight 350ms ease-in-out both;
}

/* moveFromLeft */

.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromLeft li {
-webkit-animation: moveFromLeft 350ms ease-in-out both;
animation: moveFromLeft 350ms ease-in-out both;
}

/* moveToRight */

.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToRight li {
-webkit-animation: moveToRight 350ms ease-in-out both;
animation: moveToRight 350ms ease-in-out both;
}

/* moveToLeft */

.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToLeft li {
-webkit-animation: moveToLeft 350ms ease-in-out both;
animation: moveToLeft 350ms ease-in-out both;
}

  /* Animation Delays */

.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToLeft li:first-child,
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromRight li:first-child,
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToRight li:nth-child(4),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromLeft li:nth-child(4) {
-webkit-animation-delay: 0ms;
animation-delay: 0ms;
}

.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToLeft li:nth-child(2),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromRight li:nth-child(2),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToRight li:nth-child(3),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromLeft li:nth-child(3) {
-webkit-animation-delay: 90ms;
animation-delay: 90ms;
}

.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToLeft li:nth-child(3),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromRight li:nth-child(3),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToRight li:nth-child(2),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromLeft li:nth-child(2) {
-webkit-animation-delay: 180ms;
animation-delay: 180ms;
}

.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToLeft li:nth-child(4),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromRight li:nth-child(4),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToRight li:first-child,
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromLeft li:first-child  {
-webkit-animation-delay: 270ms;
animation-delay: 270ms;
}

/* Animations */

@-webkit-keyframes moveFromRight {
0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(600%); }
100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveFromLeft {
0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-600%); }
100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveToRight {
0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }
100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(600%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveToLeft {
0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }
100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-600%); }
}

@keyframes moveFromRight {
0% { transform: translateX(600%); }
100% { transform: translateX(0); }
}

@keyframes moveFromLeft {
0% { transform: translateX(-600%); }
100% { transform: translateX(0); }
}

@keyframes moveToRight {
0% { transform: translateX(0%); }
100% { transform: translateX(600%); }
}

@keyframes moveToLeft {
0% { transform: translateX(0%); }
100% { transform: translateX(-600%); }
}

.mi-slider {
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

 /* Media Queries */
 @media screen and (max-width: 910px){
.mi-slider nav {
    max-width: 90%;
}
.mi-slider nav a {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 40px 10px 30px 14px;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 740px){
.mi-slider {
    height: 300px;
}
.mi-slider nav {
    top: 220px;
}
}

 @media screen and (max-width: 490px){ 
.mi-slider {
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
}

.mi-slider ul {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    bottom: auto;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.mi-slider ul li {
    -webkit-animation: none !important;
    animation: none !important;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0) !important;
    transform: translateX(0) !important;
    padding: 10px 3px;
    min-width: 140px;
}

.mi-slider nav {
    display: none;
}
}
```

Comment: Couldn't understand what elements you are referring

Comment: There is a gap between the product items and the black horizontal navigation bar.I want to decrease that gap.The css above creates a slider which displays several product items and when you click on the navigation bar,it disappears to the left and a new set of products appear